# Multi GPU CIFAR10 example taking more time as the number of GPU is increasing. I am using eight Tesla K80 GPU

Tags: tensorflow, multi-gpu

I am running Multi GPU CIFAR10 example. I observed that as I am increasing the number of GPU in the example, time taken to train is increasing.

nvidia-smi -l 1 command shows the expected utilization and behavior of the GPUs, but the time taken to train model is taking more with more number of GPUs which is unexpected.

I don't know if I am missing any configuration settings before running the example.
I also tried to run MNIST on multi GPUs and I faced similar problem with GPU. Basically I was trying to collect some statistics for multi GPU.

As I am increasing number of GPUs by giving values `for i in xrange(num_gpus):` I am seeing more time is being taken. Is anything wrong with code?

```py
start_time = time.time()
```

def train():

```py
with tf.device('/cpu:0'):

    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])

    W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 10]))
    b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))

    #y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x, W) + b)

    y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])

    global_step = tf.get_variable( 'global_step', [], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0), trainable=False)

    op = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5)

for i in xrange(4):
        with tf.device('/gpu:%d' % i):
          with tf.name_scope('%s_%d' % (TOWER_NAME, i)) as scope:


                #batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(100)
                #batch_xs, batch_ys = queue.dequeue_many(100)
                y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x, W) + b)
                #print(batch_xs)

                cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y_ * tf.log(y), reduction_indices=[1]))
                tower_gradient = op.compute_gradients(cross_entropy)
                tower_grads.append(tower_gradient)

grads = average_gradients(tower_grads)
apply_gradient_op = op.apply_gradients(grads, global_step=global_step)

sess = tf.InteractiveSession(config=tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=True, log_device_placement=True))
#coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
#enqueue_threads = qr.create_threads(sess, coord=coord, start=True)
tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
for _ in range(1000):
    data_batch, label_batch = mnist.train.next_batch(100)
    #data_batch, label_batch = sess.run([batch_xs,batch_ys])
    sess.run(apply_gradient_op,feed_dict={x:data_batch, y_:label_batch})
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y,1), tf.argmax(y_,1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
print(sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images, y_: mnist.test.labels}))
#coord.request_stop()
#coord.join(enqueue_threads)
sess.close()

train()
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Thanks & Regards

Comment: This does not look like a *programming* question. In fact, it appears to be off-topic, in asking about "general computing hardware/software". I would suggest revising this.

Comment: @njuffa Thanks for response. But I am facing issues in using Multi GPU. I am using cifar10_multi_gpu_train example code as is but facing issues.

Comment: There is no *specific* question asked here. In addition, questions on this site must be *programming* questions.

Comment: @njuffa  I have added my code in the question. I am trying to use 4 GPUs for training the MNIST. But I am realizing that time taken to train model is more with more GPUs which is unexpected.

Comment: I still don't see *question* (a sentence with a question mark at the end).

Comment: @njuffa  added the question.